# Force logout a ServiceStack user by id

Tags: authentication, servicestack, logout, servicestack-bsd

I'm implementing "Block user" feature on my ServiceStack 3.9 project, when a site administrator is able to block/remove registered users. But unfortunately I couldn't find a way to close opened session for a blocked (removed) user.

**Updated:**

I'm just a novice and I use the most common default configuration (MS SQL Server) with nothing special (e.g. Redis etc.). I had seen SocialBootstrapApi project as example.

**Question:**

So the question is how to logout a user by its id on the server side?

Comment: You haven't said how you are implementing sessions and if you are using standard ServiceStack authentication. This isn't a trivial task, as you are going to have to keep track of all session id's belonging to a user, which is not standard functionality.

Comment: I used usual ServiceStack 3.* authentication engine with my custom session  object as described on https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization without anything special.

Comment: Are you using an in memory cache provider or another such as Redis?

Comment: No, just default configuration with ms sql server. I'm a novice in this technology. :)